# Excel - sum given a condition in a relative column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Imagine I have this (time)sheet:

```
Hours | Text
------+----------------------
3     | fixing PRA-345
4.5   | refactoring PRA-222
5     | PRA-345 and stuff
```

And I want to calculate how much cumulative time one has spent on a ticket with a given number.

In other words sum the hours based on the text in a neighbouring cell.

Can you do it without extra column? what I did was to make an extra column that returned either the number, if given text was present (via REGEXMATCH) or 0. And then I ran a SUM on that column. Having this solved without extra column would be nice ;)

**Expected output**

In my case if would be enough for a given string to find the total sum of hours. So if I cell(say it's D1) has the hardwired text, such as "PRA-345" I want the cell to the left(E1) to display the total hours(8 in this case)

Comment: `SUMIF()` supports wildcards (in Excel at least). I'd give that a go.

Comment: `REGEXMATCH` is Google Sheets and doesn't exist in Excel. If you're using Sheets, best to stick to its appropriate tags.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the expected output?

Comment: @Iamblichus you are right, I didn't specify the output. Edited the answer, is that better?

Comment: Thank you. In this case, I think [Krzysztof's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65944254) provides a solution to your problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you can try

```
=QUERY({A1:A11,ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B11,"PRA-\d+"))}, 
           "select Col2, sum(Col1) where Col1 is not null 
            group by Col2 label Col2 'Tickets', sum(Col1) 'Sums' ",1)
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Sir, you basically quadrupled my knowledge of spreadsheets ;)

Comment: One question if I may: how is ArrayFormula different from the curly braces? Apparently sometimes it is interchangeable, other times not...

Comment: To understand the difference compare this `={A2:A3+B2:B3}` to this `=ArrayFormula(A2:A3+B2:B3)`

Comment: My first hunch is that curly braces only allow ranges as arguments. on the other hand `={1,2,3}` clearly works...

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you need?

[image]

```
=sum(filter(B5:B,regexmatch(C5:C,E5)))
```

#### Reference:

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en)

Comment: nice solution as well, thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

An additional column will need to be created to save the "ticket code" of the problem and then the simple functions provided above will implement it perfectly.